# Function inside an object gets wrong context

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor:

```
var ProfileDialog = function (containerObj) {
    this.init = function () {
        this.container = containerObj;
        let content = document.createElement('div');
        content.innerText = 'Dialog here';
        this.container.appendChild(content);
        this.container.style.display = 'none';
    };

    this.init();
};
```

Then I am extending the prototype of the constructor like this:

```
ProfileDialog.prototype.open = function () {
    this.container.style.display = 'block';
}

var dlg = new ProfileDialog(document.body)
dlg.open();
```

This works fine, but if I try to put `.open()` inside an object like this:

```
ProfileDialog.prototype.actions = {
    open: function () {
        this.container.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

var dlg = new ProfileDialog(document.body)
dlg.actions.open();
```

It fails with an error

> functional.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(…)

because of the wrong context passed to the function.

How do I make sure that independently of the nesting, context would be always the instantiated object?

Comment: `dlg.actions.open.call(dlg);`

Comment: This isn't "context", it's a value that is set by the call.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try binding 'this' to actions.open

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you save `this` to `that` before and take it as a closure for the `init` function.

```
var ProfileDialog = function (containerObj) {
    var that = this;
    this.init = function () {
        that.container = containerObj;
        let content = document.createElement('div');
        content.innerText = 'Dialog here';
        that.container.appendChild(content);
        that.container.style.display = 'none';
    };

    this.init();
};
```